# Перенос строки от пробела у чекбокса

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, sass

Добрый день, никак не могу понять почему от пробела происходит перенос строк, товарищ сказал что запретить перенос будет костыльно, как поправить эту ситуацию?

ЗЫ. Как подключить SASS в сниппет, увы, не знаю.

```css
p.trackname {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.panel-default {
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: none;
}

.panel-default .panel-heading {
  color: #333;
  background: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #bbbbbb;
  border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
}

.panel-default .panel-body {
  padding: 30px 0px;
}

.panel-default span {
  margin-left: 45px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.panel {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.checkbox {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background: #000;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.checkbox label {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.5px;
  left: 2.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #000, 0px 1px 0px #000;
}

.checkbox label:after {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 2.48px;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0;
}

.checkbox input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked+label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="value1" name="value1" />
  <label for="value1"><span>12312312312312312312312312312312312312312312321</span></label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="value2" name="value2" />
  <label for="value2"><span>Характеристика 2</span></label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="value3" name="value3" />
  <label for="value3"><span>Характеристика 3</span></label>
</div>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Для того, чтобы не было переноса от пробела можете использовать неразрываной пробел - `&nbsp;`
2. Для того, чтобы запретить перенос вовсе - можете использовать `white-space:nowrap;`, но это действительно лучше использовать в тех случаях, когда количество текста не будет ломать верстку.
3. Можете поиграться с переносом слов: `<wbr>`, `&shy;`, `word-break: break-all;` или `hyphens:auto;`.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте заменить пробел на дефис. Всё-равно переносится? Значит по пикселям текст не влезает в ширину `label` т.к. ему задано свойство `width:25px`, вот текст и переносится. Сделайте ширину `label` больше и будет вам радость =)

Comment: Нет, если писать в одну строку вообще пофиг (без пробелов)

Comment: А вот если поставишь пробел - перенесет строку

Comment: @user234223 Пробел занимает много пикселей, если можно уменьшить текст и нужно чтобы label имел такую ширину(строго 25 пикселей) - напишите `label { font-size: 10px;}` . И играйтесь с размером шрифта, пока весь текст будет влазить и пока не найдете желаемый размер шрифта.

Comment: @user234223 По поводу пробел занимает много пикселей - это не всегда, а конкретно при вашем `font-size`

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю что вы имеете ввиду, но я обновил сниппет - дело не в размере label судя по всему, я написал кучу в одну строку.

Comment: А поставь пробел и эта куча перенесется

Comment: Может дело в том, что `span` который лежит в `label` имеет `margin-left:45px;`. Получается отступ, больше чем ширина `label`, попробуйте убрать этот отступ